# If I have a MySQL table with multiple colum values the same, how do I delete all but two of the most recent entries?

Tags: php, mysql

I know this sounds like a duplicate of a few questions, and it may well be, but I've searched through and tried my own implementation of several possible solutions but all of them seem to result in some form of infinite recursion that just chews 100% CPU and does nothing.  That could be because I'm doing it wrong or they aren't appropriate for me, I don't know.

I have a MySQL table structured as follows :

```
        +--------+------+-----+-------+--------+--------+----------------+
        |   id   | fid  | bid | dec_a | varc_a | varc_b | dec_b | varc_c |
        +--------+------+-----+-------+--------+--------+----------------+
        | 106861 | 4192 |  22 | 1.40  | blah   | blahbr | 0.2   | blahca |
        | 108620 | 4192 |  22 | 1.55  | blah   | blahbe | 0.2   | blahca |
        | 108621 | 4192 |  22 | 1.55  | blah   | blahbq | 0.2   | blahca | 
        | 108622 | 4192 |  22 | 1.55  | blah   | blahbw | 0.2   | blahca | 
        | 108623 | 4192 |  22 | 1.55  | blah   | blahbe | 0.2   | blahca | 
        | 108624 | 4192 |  22 | 1.55  | blah   | blahbf | 0.2   | blahca | 
        | 106863 | 4192 |  33 | 1.40  | blah   | blahba | 0.2   | blahca | 
        +--------+------+-----+-------+--------+--------+-------+--------+
```

The "id" value is a BIGINT auto-incrementing value and the data is added in proper chronological order from the source, so I am viewing this as the timestamp.

To establish which data is duplicated I am using the "fid", "bid", "varc_a", "dec_b" and "varc_c" columns. From the example above you can see that there are 6 duplicates based on those columns and those are the first six rows, the seventh row shows where there is variation in the "bid" column but obviously any variation in any of those columns excludes the row as a duplicate.

I can easily visualise what I want to do : There are potentially millions of entries in the database, I want to exclude the 2 most recent rows of data based on the entry id where the "fid", "bid", "varc_a", "dec_b" and "varc_c" column values are the same and then sweep away what's left.

For the life of me I can't figure out how to do that using just MySQL and, as I say, all of the questions and answers I've looked at don't seem to be doing what I want to do or I'm not understanding what's proposed.

I know I can do this with PHP+MySQL by trawling through the data and removing the duplicates but considering I can do it in such a horribly inefficient way quite easily I'm thinking that I'm missing something obvious and I should be able to do it with MySQL alone ?

**: Note :**

Mike's answer is excellent and it did precisely what I need with a little tweaking given the context of my question.  What I ended up using was this :

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS keepers1, keepers2, keepers_all;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE keepers1 (KEY(id)) ENGINE=MEMORY AS 
SELECT fid, bid, varc_a, dec_b, var_c, MAX(id) AS id 
FROM market_prices
GROUP BY fid, bid, varc_a, dec_b, varc_c;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE keepers2 AS
SELECT fid, bid, varc_a, dec_b, varc_c, MAX(id) AS id
FROM market_prices AS k
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM keepers1 WHERE id = k.id)
GROUP BY  fid, bid, varc_a, dec_b, varc_c;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE keepers_all (KEY(id)) ENGINE=MEMORY AS
SELECT id FROM keepers1
UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM keepers2;

DELETE k.* FROM market_prices AS k WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 2 FROM keepers_all WHERE id = k.id);
```

When grouping be sure to just use the columns that are duplicated and in that last statement your SELECT should be the number of records you want to keep, I needed a SELECT 2 at the end there.

Time to raise a glass to the man of the hour!

Comment: you need a date field

Comment: I can add a julian timestamp field no problem by storing time("U") along with the record when it's inserted, but as I said in my question the id of the entry is an AUTO_INCREMENT and the data is parsed and added in proper chronological order from the source.  So adding a timestamp, at least in my head, is duplicating the functionality provided by the ID AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY value.  The ID can be viewed as a timestamp.

Comment: With a timestamp you can do date operations like in your delete's where clause `and datefield < X` where X is current date minus some date element. So you only delete things created more than a day ago, or whatever. That's a lot easier with a timestamp than a auto increment. And I mean an actual `datetime` field so you can use MySQL's date functions.

Comment: My problem is that I don't think there is a concept of "X < Y" as a length of time here because this data doesn't really "time out", the oldest record is considered redundant when there are three records at which point it should be removed and leaving the two most recently added records.  The actual timestamp of the record is somewhat irrelevant because one set of duplicate data could span 24 minutes and another could span 24 hours, the length of time is variable and there will be tens of thousands of potential duplicates at any one time which is why I didn't timestamp it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a solution for your problem.

However, since there is no date-time column I am assuming that the id column is the primary key. And it is `Auto_increment`. So my assumption is that the larger the number the newer the record. (it should be true unless you had some old data dumps into the table)

Make sure you back up your data before you delete as this will cause you a permanent data lost. Even better, you can make a copy of the current table into a different table and work on he new table to make sure the logic below is correct. Then change the queries that I have below to read from `tbl_new` instead on `tbl`

you can duplicate your table via something like

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_new LIKE tbl;
```

I have left comments for every query

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS keepers1, keepers2, keepers_all;
-- get the #1 top records
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE keepers1 (KEY(id)) ENGINE=MEMORY AS
SELECT fid, bid, dec_a, varc_a, varc_b, dec_b, varc_c, MAX(id) AS id
FROM tbl
GROUP BY fid, bid, dec_a, varc_a, varc_b, dec_b, varc_c;

-- get the #2 top records
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE keepers2 AS
SELECT fid, bid, dec_a, varc_a, varc_b, dec_b, varc_c, MAX(id) AS id
FROM tbl AS k
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM keepers1 WHERE id = k.id)
GROUP BY fid, bid, dec_a, varc_a, varc_b, dec_b, varc_c;


-- create a temp table where you have all he ids that you want to keep
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE keepers_all (KEY(id)) ENGINE=MEMORY AS
SELECT id FROM keepers1
UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM keepers2;


-- delete all records that you don't want to keep
DELETE k.* FROM tbl AS k WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM keepers_all WHERE id = k.id);
```

if this is a one time clean up job then you should be able to execute the queries from the console. but if you are looking for a recruiting Job them you should probably take this code and put it in a procedure.

Note: here I am using MEMORY TEMPORARY tables for better performance. You may run into an issue that say ["Table is Full"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/full-table.html) this is because you have too many records. then you can increase the value max_heap_table_size for the session
something like

```
SET SESSION tmp_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2; -- this will set it to 2G
SET SESSION max_heap_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2; -- this will set it to 2G
```

This will give you your current value

```
SELECT VARIABLES LIKE 'max_heap_table_size';
SELECT VARIABLES LIKE 'tmp_table_size';
```

Comment: Wow, OK. I think I'm roughly following this and I'm quite pleased that I'm not missing something simple, at least not for me that is. It's going to take me a little time to get my head around this and get it tested but if I'm reading this right I think you've solved my problem how I want it to be solved. I'll be sure to come back and upvote and so on when I've, fingers crossed, got it going.

Comment: If I knew who you were, I'd buy you a beer.  Well done!  Works like a charm.

Comment: lol. I am glad it worked for you with no error :) now I feel good :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html). You can create the stored procedure either via PHP, or MySQL directly:

**Creating via PHP**

```
$createProc = "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `remove_dups`;
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `remove_dups`( In id varchar(255))
    BEGIN
        ...my code...
    END;";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

//create the stored procedure
$stmt = $conn->prepare($createProc);

$stmt->execute();
```

**Create via MySQL GUI**

Simply put the create statement in the text box and run it (against the proper DB):

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `remove_dups`( In id varchar(255))
    BEGIN
        ...my code...
    END;";
```

Then you can call this procedure either from PHP or MySQL.

In your stored proc, you'll want to declare some variables to store the values in and do a check to find rows with the same values (using a [cursor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html)), and then check the id against the previous row's. If all the values are the same, delete to one with the lower id.

Comment: Thanks for the tip off about stored procedures, something I need to look in to more given the change in scale of my application recently. I might end up using a stored proc in conjunction with Mike's answer as this cleanup operation needs to run hourly.

Comment: @MisterB Why would it need to run hourly? It should run *once* and then after that, you should alter the insert statements to only insert if not duplicate to another row in those fields.

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't know enough about stored procedures yet. Mike's answer fits with my task right now.  I'm going to have to do some reading on this subject sooner rather than later *-blush-*

Comment: @MisterB even if you don't use stored procs, my previous comment still is true. This should be a 1-time cleanup and then you need to alter code so it no longer inserts those duplicate rows. You should *NEVER* be adding invalid data to a DB.

Comment: It's not that I'm adding invalid data, I'm adding new data which makes the older data redundant.

Comment: @MisterB Yes, and that should all be fixed after you run this "remove duplicates" code. Then in the future, when your application tries to add new data, it will check to see if there's a duplicate row already there, if so, it won't insert the new row. Instead (assuming you want the newer id), it will update the existing row's id # (or do nothing if you want to keep the old one). That way, you never need to run the duplicate-checking code ever again

Comment: Yeah I get what you're saying, it's the "... my code ..." bit in the middle I need to figure out now ;)  I'm not saying your answer is wrong, far from it, I'm saying that I don't know how to implement what you're saying... Yet.