# How to move duplicate record from one table to another and display as error to duplicated data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to write a test case for a table in which - if ORGID-SITEID-WONUM-STATUS-STATUSDATE combination is duplicated then move this record into error table and display '%ORGID-SITEID-WONUM-STATUS-STATUSDATE combination is duplicated%'. I found duplicated record by

```
SELECT ORGID, SITEID, WONUM, STATUS, CHANGEDATE, count(*) 
FROM BP_Wostatus_2t 
GROUP BY ORGID, SITEID, WONUM, STATUS, CHANGEDATE
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

Comment: does this all have to be done in mysql or some other language as well (PHP, Java, etc..)?

Comment: It can be done via SQL. You should read the answer in this other question as it deliver the same concept http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27002850/if-i-have-a-mysql-table-with-multiple-colum-values-the-same-how-do-i-delete-all/27003193#27003193.  But instead of deleting records you would insert the records elsewhere. Also you would not need to create the table keepers2 in you case. I hope that answer helps you. If you can't fingure it out I will post and answer for you tomorrow

Comment: Do you want to also leave a copy in BP_Wostatus_2t? Or you want to completely delete that record?